# Research on difficulty algorithm

Tags: monero-research-lab, mining-technical-details, difficulty-algorithm

A new difficulty algorithm is said to be researched in https://getmonero.org/design-goals/, with a new MRL paper underway.

I see nothing new on https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/ about this. Is this research continuing, cancelled, or paused ?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like its a WIP (Work in Progress), we can read some info [here](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/commit/60a63a3b5d3f50afd504a76193925f0a132b7bb4). I wouldn't rush anything related to the difficulty algorithm or other essential aspects.